# Issue with EDB Bart utility and archive command

Tags: postgresql-10

I m having a strange issue with EDB bart.cfg and archive_command in Postgres 10.13. Actually archive logs are generating at /u01/app/Postgres/archivelogs/, but don't know why the ARCHIVE_PATH is "/u01/app/Postgres/backups/prod2.naveed.com/archived_wals" showing up in bart show-servers. Because of this, my incremental backups are failing

**bart.cfg**

```
[BART]
bart_host= postgres@localhost
backup_path = /u01/app/Postgres/backups
pg_basebackup_path = /u01/app/EDB_Postgres10/bin/pg_basebackup

[prod2.naveed.com]
host = prod2.naveed.com
port = 5432
user = postgres
cluster_owner = postgres
pg_basebackup_path = /u01/app/EDB_Postgres10/bin/pg_basebackup
tablespace_path = 16393=/u01/app/Postgres/tablespaces
archive_command='cp %p /u01/app/Postgres/archivelogs/%f'
allow_incremental_backups = enabled
```

**bart show-servers -s prod2.naveed.com**

```
SERVER NAME         : prod2.naveed.com
HOST NAME           : prod2.naveed.com
USER NAME           : postgres
PORT                : 5432
REMOTE HOST         :
RETENTION POLICY    : none
DISK UTILIZATION    : 47.21 MB
WARNING: not marking any WALs as unused WALs, the WAL file '/u01/app/Postgres/backups/prod2.naveed.com/archived_wals/000000010000000000000008' is required, yet not available in archived_wals directory
NUMBER OF ARCHIVES  : 0
ARCHIVE PATH        : /u01/app/Postgres/backups/prod2.naveed.com/archived_wals
ARCHIVE COMMAND     : cp %p /u01/app/Postgres/archivelogs/%f
XLOG METHOD         : fetch
WAL COMPRESSION     : disabled
TABLESPACE PATH(s)  :
                     16393 = /u01/app/Postgres/tablespaces
INCREMENTAL BACKUP  : ENABLED
DESCRIPTION         :
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have an option to set the

```
Archive_path = /u01/app/postgres/archivelogs
```

in `bart.cfg` else BART will take the default path.

`archive_path` (optional) – Specify the path where archived WAL files will be stored. The default location of the archived WAL files is the BART backup catalog (backup_path/server_name/archived_wals).